# Easier suggestions in Intellij IDEA (no `CTRL+Space` and fuzzy search)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, autosuggest, code-completion

I've installed IDEA today, on macOS and am wondering a couple of things to adapt usability to my needs:

- how to **always show autocompletion automatically, as a sort of continuous suggestion**, rather than having to always manually press <kbd>⌃Space</kbd>?
- how to **make the search among autocompletion fuzzier**, without needing to type all the initial letters? Something like typing "fb" and it will match the variable `foobar`, rather than having to type "foob".

Answer (score 2):

- Yes, this is achievable. Go to Settings -> Editor -> General -> Code Completion and check 'Show suggestions as you type'
- Partially achievable. You have to go again to Settings -> Editor -> General -> Code Completion and uncheck 'Match case'. This will help you with the completion but the results are not always as expected.

Tested on IDEA 2020.3

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, that's more or less what I've found out already: – The *"Match case"* option unfortunately does not really help. – The *"Show suggestions as you type"* doesn't really change anything in the behaviour; I still have to press <kbd>CTRL+Space</kbd> 